# Expand and transform dataframe. Compare each row with all other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Please compare Bob's byte array with the byte arrays of all the other people. Do this with every person.

```py
columns = ["pasta", "potatoes", "rice"]
data = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
index = ["tom", "jenny", "bob"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns, index=index)

# output
#        pasta  potatoes  rice
# tom        1         0     1
# jenny      0         1     1
# bob        1         1     1
```

Explanation of data: 1 = likes food of columnname // 0 doesn't like food of columnname.

I want to compare every person's bytearray to the byte array of all the other persons. 1 if they differ; 0 if they don't differ.

So wished output would look like

```py
             pasta potatoes rice
tom   jenny  1     1        0
tom   bob    0     1        0
jenny tom    1     1        0
jenny bob    1     0        0
bob   tom    0     1        0
bob   jenny  1     0        0
```

I know that byte-array of "bob-jenny" is the same as "jenny-bob" but I need it that way. I don't care if it is going to be a dataframe with multiindex or if the persons are in two distinct columns.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate the permutations, then slice and compare:

```
from itertools import permutations

a, b = map(list, zip(*permutations(df.index, r=2)))

out = (df.loc[a].ne(df.loc[b].to_numpy()).astype(int)
         .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, b]))
       )
```

Output:

```
             pasta  potatoes  rice
tom   jenny      1         1     0
      bob        0         1     0
jenny tom        1         1     0
      bob        1         0     0
bob   tom        0         1     0
      jenny      1         0     0
```

You can easily adapt to [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in place of `permutations` (the total information is the same):

Output:

```
             pasta  potatoes  rice
tom   jenny      1         1     0
      bob        0         1     0
jenny bob        1         0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) first:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index])
idx = idx[idx.get_level_values(0) != idx.get_level_values(1)]
```

Or solution with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
from itertools import permutations

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(permutations(df.index, 2)))
```

And then use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with compare by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with casting boolean to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df = df.reindex(idx, level=0).ne(df.reindex(idx, level=1)).astype(int)
print (df)
             pasta  potatoes  rice
tom   jenny      1         1     0
      bob        0         1     0
jenny tom        1         1     0
      bob        1         0     0
bob   tom        0         1     0
      jenny      1         0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `cross` join and groupby()

```
d = df.reset_index().join(df.reset_index(),how = 'cross',lsuffix='_').set_index(['index_','index']).rename(lambda x: x.rstrip('_'),axis=1).groupby(level=0,axis=1).all()

(~d).astype(int).loc[d.index.get_level_values(0)!=d.index.get_level_values(1)]
```

Output:

```
              pasta  potatoes  rice
index_ index                       
tom    jenny      1         1     0
       bob        0         1     0
jenny  tom        1         1     0
       bob        1         0     0
bob    tom        0         1     0
       jenny      1         0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.DataFrame((df.values != df.values[:, None]).astype(int).reshape(-1, 3), 
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index]))
 .set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
 .loc[lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(0) != x.index.get_level_values(1)])
```

Output:

```
             pasta  potatoes  rice
tom   jenny      1         1     0
      bob        0         1     0
jenny tom        1         1     0
      bob        1         0     0
bob   tom        0         1     0
      jenny      1         0     0
```